# Redirect Tag to Post with the same name

Tags: tags, redirect

I would like to check if the tag name is the title of a post. And load that post page instead of a tag page.

I have post_type "Cities" and suppose that users will tag normal posts with city names. And when user selects a tag, I would like to check if a "Cities" post exists with this tag name. And show this post if it does.

I am thinking of redirecting from tag page to post page, but don't know when and how to run the check. Is it the right way?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted. Anyway, is the tag also a custom taxonomy or wordpress default tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code from this article:
http://metinsaylan.com/wordpress/2011/02/15/how-to-redirect-to-single-post-page-if-there-is-one-post-in-categorytag/

It checks `$wp_query->post_count` and redirects to the only article of an archive if there is just one.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange, Waleri! Because this was your first answer I translated it to English. Please don’t use any other language here – otherwise, it would be too hard for other readers to understand what you have written. Also, always add an explanation to your answer, don’t post just links. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_page_by_title() function to obtain the post object that has the same title. Link to the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title. Here is the code you should place before get_header() in tags.php. It will help you redirect to the single post (or any other CPT if you're using that) if found with the same title.

```
$current_post = get_page_by_title(single_tag_title(), OBJECT, "post");
if($current_post !== null) {
    wp_redirect($current_post->guid);
}
```